# collection from customer model is not retrieving updated data when controller is refreshed from browser in magento2

Tags: collections, model, magento2

i have created one custom front end module that print the data retrieved from customer mode(details of customers).everything is fine when i calling controller from browser , i am printing the customer details in table format as i required.later i manually updated customer data in phpmyadmin console .now i am **refreshing the controller**.But  **not printing the updated data**.i need to delete generation file and update the custom module with php bin/magento setup:magento to get the updated data of customer model

this is my collection file written in block folder

what might be the problem for not retrieving the updated data...???please discuss

```
<?php
namespace MageClass\First\Block;
class Details extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
     protected $_gridFactory;
     public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $gridFactory,
        array $data = []
     ) {
        $this->_gridFactory = $gridFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        //get collection of data
        $collection = $this->_gridFactory->create()->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Users List'));
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        if ($this->getCollection()) {
            // create pager block for collection
            $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                'Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager',
                'mageclass.first.record.pager'
            )->setCollection(
                $this->getCollection() // assign collection to pager
            );
            $this->setChild('pager', $pager);// set pager block in layout
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    // method for get pager html
    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }
}
?
```

>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i could found the answer finally .Actually the problem is cache.i disabled the full page cache in cache management of admin panel.Now i am retrieving updated collection every time